# My PHP.ini file is gone; how can I restore it?

Tags: php

I was wondering, is there any way to load the php.ini file from memory? From my understanding the php.ini is only loaded during start, so theoretically I should be able to load it somehow from memory?

Since something pretty strange happened, perhaps a loop gone wrong, but php.ini suddenly died, and my nginx error and notice logs seem to have received several hundred thousand extra errors before crashing as well.

PHP still seems to be running and I replaced the log files and fixed the script, but my php.ini is still empty, and I'm pretty scared of waiting for the next time I run PHP to see if it'll regenerate a new one or what.

Comment: Since this question isn't about programming specifically, rather about configuration of PHP, it'd be best asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I don't think there's any value in asking this on S/F - the answer is pretty much that you can't do this. If you used the `phpinfo` command, either on the command line or using a script, it will try to look it up. Try it though, just in case: `php -i`. I suspect it will just give you default settings. Download a new copy of PHP and fish out the ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** server is still running, and you want to do this **IN** php take a look at the `ini_get_all` function. From my understanding there are two (?) functions in php which can do this, `get_cfg_vars` and `ini_get_all` where get_cfg_vars fetches directly from php.ini, and the latter returns directly from runtime.

Otherwise, you can get all the config vars from shell using php -i, but i would prefer getting it as an array.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php for more information.

Comment: That would be most interesting if the settings persist in memory. Have you checked to ensure that it is not just delivering a default set of values, in the event that the ini file is not available? Is the behaviour the same across the console and the web?

Comment: I haven't testet but reading from manual it seems that a user has tested this and come to the conclusion that get_cfg_var fetches from php.ini directly while init_get_all fetches from file loaded at runtime.
See link for comment
[link](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could get all of the settings you'll need in order to restore the php.ini file using the "php -i" command (checked it with linux, but I'm pretty sure it would be the same with windows).

Comment: This will not return the right settings - `php -i` from the shell will call the CLI version of PHP, which usually has its own ini file (with different defaults).